# React-Native-Blob RNFetchBlob does not create file

Tags: react-native

I'm using

```
var blob = new Blob(  [RNFetchBlob.wrap(image.path)] , {
    type: 'image'
});
```

To upload to Amazon S3 from iOS. But this uploads JSON data rather than the file itself (i.e. 160 bytes!). Any ideas?

> {"_data":{"blobId":"3dce8216-b17a-4423-beda-ecf4f189ad14","offset":0,"size":160,"type":"binary/octet-stream"}}